# 1.3 to 2.0 migration error (Notice: Undefined index: controller in Dispatcher.php)

Tags: cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3

I am doing migration of cakephp 1.3 to 2.0 . i follow the cakephp migration guide but after the upgrade i get following error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: controller in C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php


( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MissingControllerException' with message 'Controller class Controller could not be found.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php on line 83
( ! ) MissingControllerException: Controller class Controller could not be found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php on line 83
```

Can any one guide me what i have done wrong if some one already pass through same situation?
Any help will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check the source

The error message comes from [the dispatch function](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php#L83):

```
public function dispatch(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response, $additionalParams = array()) {
    if ($this->asset($request->url, $response) || $this->cached($request->here)) {
        return;
    }

    $request = $this->parseParams($request, $additionalParams);
    Router::setRequestInfo($request);
    $controller = $this->_getController($request, $response);

    if (!($controller instanceof Controller)) {
        throw new MissingControllerException(array( # line 83
            'class' => Inflector::camelize($request->params['controller']) . 'Controller',
            'plugin' => empty($request->params['plugin']) ? null : Inflector::camelize($request->params['plugin'])
        ));
    }

    return $this->_invoke($controller, $request, $response);
}
```

Which means: No route matched the request.

A common cause for that is to [miss loading the default routes](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/app/Config/routes.php#L44) which is responsible for the [catchall routes](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.0.0/lib/Cake/Config/routes.php) which [in 1.3 are automatic](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.0/cake/libs/router.php#L844-L846).

Comment: Thanks for answer , after adding  the code 
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
the error goes away :)